# Detect vertical rectangles of almost constant color in noisy image

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have a noisy image with several rectangles. Visually speaking, the rectangles are quite obvious. They are all **vertical or horizontal**, they don't appear at different angles. Their color/intensity is also quite constant. **I want to detect those rectangles**, and if possible detect rectangles inside other rectangles or on top/accross.

**Original image:**

[image: Original Image]

**Image with expected rectangles/squares** (there may be thin vertical lines, whether they are detected as rectangles or not is not important):

[image: Image with expected rectangles]

From what I gathered, it's quite a manual job requiring to

1. convert the image in gray scale 8 bit (my image is already in gray scale)
2. add gaussian noise to smooth the image
3. convert the result into black and white, eg with `adaptiveThreshold`
4. dilate the result to try to join parts that are not touching anymore
5. erode the result to remove small unwanted noise
6. run some algorithm to detect the shapes

**I'm currently computing the following image:**

[image: Black and white threshold image]

Notes on the result:

- there's no noise (though on some other images I still get small patches of noise here and there)
- the rectangles are not all closed
- one small rectangle/squared on the left may now be difficult to spot next to the vertical line

**My questions are**

- Is there a better way to do this?
- How do I go on detecting the rectangles, which are currently not all closed? Knowing they are always horizontal or vertical and of almost constant color should help.

Note that I also tried Canny but I don't get good results.

I'm using OpenCV 4.1.2 with Python 3.7.2. Here's my current code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy
import platform
import sys

print("Python version: {}\nOpenCV version: {}".format(platform.python_version(), cv2.__version__))

# Used variables:
# For gaussian blur
gaussianBlur = 11
# For threshold
meanType = cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C
meanTypeName = "Mean"
blockSize = 17
c = 3
# For close/open
growSize = 6
shrinkSize = 3

# Import image.
imageName = sys.argv[1]
image = cv2.imread(imageName)

# Convert to gray scale 8 bit, blur then take threshold.
grayscaled = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayscaled, (gaussianBlur, gaussianBlur), 0)
thresholded = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred, 255, meanType, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, blockSize, c)

# Close then Open to try to "close" the rectangles and remove noise.
rectClose = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (growSize,growSize))
rectOpen = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (shrinkSize,shrinkSize))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresholded, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, rectClose)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, rectOpen)

result = mask

# Compute contours and display them on the gray scale image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(result, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
resultWithContours = grayscaled
cv2.drawContours(resultWithContours, contours, -1, (0,0,255), cv2.FILLED)

# Display threshold image and original with detected contours.
both = numpy.concatenate([result, resultWithContours], axis=0)
cv2.imshow("{} Block Size={} C={}".format(meanTypeName, blockSize, c), both)

# Save both threshold and original with detected contours.
cv2.imwrite("{}_result_{}_blockSize{}_c{}.jpg".format(imageName, meanTypeName, blockSize, c), result)
cv2.imwrite("{}_contours_{}_blockSize{}_c{}.jpg".format(imageName, meanTypeName, blockSize, c), resultWithContours)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

If the color/intensity is constant, you can use color segmentation technique(more precise than adaptive thresholding). I generally use adaptive thresholding in cases when there are couple of objects with stark contrast/color differences generally with random color palette.

But in your case since the color is consistent we can hard code the color range. Use any color picker tool to fetch the color of rectangles, you want to detect, let's say the color is `155` (gray-scale value). Then we can use `cv2.inRange()` with a lower threshold of say `150` and upper threshold of `160`. You will get a binary image from `cv2.inRange()` method which can be used to find out contours.

You may need to do the above steps a couple of times with different rectangle colors to fetch all the rectangles in the image.

Comment: The term `Color Segmentation` led me to `pyrMeanShiftFiltering` which seems to help a lot, as each rectangle has a mostly constant color.

Comment: BTW I meant https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange. But `pyrMeanShiftFiltering` would also help

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

1- filtered image with bilateral filter

2- Applied Otsu threshold (and reversed the binary image)

3- Opened the image (morphological)

4- Masked the filtered image with the opened image

5- Applied canny edge detector

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now with `findContour` and `drawContour` you can do whatever you like with the rectangles. Here is my code (C++):

```
Mat img__1, img__2,img__ = imread("E:/s.jpg", 0);
Mat filtered;

bilateralFilter(img__, filtered, 9, 5, 5);

imshow("filtered", filtered);

threshold(filtered, img__1, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);
img__1 = 255 - img__1;

imshow("Binarized by Otsu", img__1);

int k = 3;
erode(img__1, img__1, Mat::ones(k, k, CV_8U), Point(-1, -1), 1);
dilate(img__1, img__1, Mat::ones(k, k, CV_8U), Point(-1, -1), 1);

imshow("Dots removed", img__1);

img__1.convertTo(img__1, CV_32F);
filtered.convertTo(filtered, CV_32F);
img__1 = img__1 / 255.0;
multiply(filtered, img__1, img__1,1, CV_32F);
img__1.convertTo(img__1, CV_8U);

imshow("masked denoised image", img__1);

Mat canny_1;
Canny(img__1, canny_1, 30, 100);

imshow("final image", canny_1);
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Find contours won't work for the top rectangle pair, as it would be counted as a single contour and not two different rectangles.

Comment: @ZdaR Good point! but it' not a problem. After masking each pair of rectangle with drawContour, It's easy to do another Otsu thresholding on only the pixels of that shape to separate the two rectangles. But if we had more than 2 rectangles mixed with each other then that could be hard :)